# Google Chart Api Time Table

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google Chart Api Time Table.

[image]

It draw like this.

How to know when I onclick that Bar?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});

function ready(data){
    var datas = data;

    // console.log(datas[0]['event_name']);
    // alert(datas);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

    // console.log(datas[0]['event_name']);
    var arrayLength = datas.length;
    // console.log(arrayLength);

    var events = new Array();



    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President', name : '123213' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

    for ( var i = 0; i < arrayLength ; i++ ){
        dataTable.addRows([
            [datas[i]['event_name'], new Date(datas[i]['start_day']), new Date(datas[i]['end_day'])],
        ]);
    }
    // dataTable.addRows([
    // [ 'Washington', new Date(1789,03, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    // [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    // [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]
    // ]);


    chart.draw(dataTable);

    }
}
```

This is my code. When I click the bar I want to know that ID or Name.

Comment: Please put your code in codepen.io

Comment: Refer this for your answer https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events